# Instagram feed carousel

Tags: laravel, carousel

I want to create a carousel that contain my instagram photo on my website. It's already working with simple grid style. This is the section where I put the feed:

```
<div id="instagram-feed-demo" class="instagram_feed"></div>
```

and this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $.instagramFeed({
            'username': 'iipex_id',
            'container': "#instagram-feed-demo",
            'display_profile': false,
            'display_biography': false,
            'display_gallery': true,
            'get_raw_json': false,
            'callback': null,
            'styling': true,
            'items': 9,
            'items_per_row': 3,
            'margin': 1
        });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

since I want to display it as carousel, I try to put the ID and Class into carousel :

```
<div id="instagram-feed-demo" class="carousel instagram_feed" data-items="3" data-dots="false" data-loop="true" data-autoplay="true" data-lightbox="gallery"></div>
```

but it's not working. maybe I have to create another script? or I made a mistake on my carousel  ?

Comment: what the errors did it say?

Comment: There is no error, it just not working when I try to put the id and class on the carousel section

Comment: your jquery order is in place?double check it

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure that the order is right in the place

Comment: in your jquery script, you I don't see any #id loaded into your function. So it won't show in your page